# What if 2 vue instances call functions from each other other

Tags: javascript, vue.js

For example I have Profile and App instances. Both instances are created in different files: profile.js and app.js. There are also profile.html and app.js

Profile has function `getProfile`.
App has function `getApp`.

When `profile` instance is mounted it calls `getApp` function.
In `app` instance I call function `getProfile` of `profile` instance.

I putted the script sources in both files.

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="profile.js"></script>
```

So, when I load app.html. I get an error saying that there is no `profile` instance:

```
ReferenceError: profile is not defined
```

The problem is that vue intance loads before another, and it can't see second vue instance.

How to fix it?

Comment: why not defer second one? And also do you need two scripts why can't everything be in app.js itself ?

Comment: You likely shouldn't do that. Make them interact through a common parent.